# What is the default inflation destination of my account?

Tags: inflation

Lets assume I own 10% of all XLM of the network and I want to receive inflation for my XLM.

By default this option "inflation destination" is not set on my account. So question is - where does "inflation I am entitled to" go if I have not set this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unallocated inflation lumens [are returned to the fee pool](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html#how-inflation-voting-works).

Comment: So lumens I might be entitled to are returned to fee pool?

I was understanding that this "inflation destination" is more of a vote. If you are not voting, youre entitled to nothing and your portion is split among those who voted.

Comment: That's actually the same, because your portion goes to the fee pool which in turn is used to calculate the distributed lumens, see formula in the link.